# being function and an array at same time?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why is that:

```
function greeting(){
    alert('hello sir...')
}

greeting();

greeting[0] = "zero"
greeting[1] = "one"
greeting[3] ="two"
greeting[4] ="three"
greeting[5] ="four"
greeting[6] ="five"
greeting[7] ="six"
```

`console.log(greeting[5])` outputs four

```
greeting.map(i=>{
    console.log(i)
})
```

// here compaints .map is not a function

so how can greeting be trated like an Array but has not .map function??

Comment: It's not being treated like an array, but an object. `x[a]` syntax is not "array" syntax.

Comment: You have added properties to the function object referenced by `greeting` called `'0'`, `'1'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, etc.   This is because when you index the object with a non-string value, such as the number `5`, it converts the number `5` to the string `'5'` to be used as the property name. `Object.keys(greeting)` should now produce `[ '0', '1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' ]`  You could also access it with `greeting['5']`.  If you did `greeting[{}] = 42` you'd get `{ '[object Object]': 42 }` because converting `{}` to a string gives the string `'[object Object]'`, which will be the property name.

Comment: I found it very distracting that you skipped `greeting[2]`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign indexed properties on *any* object - including function objects - but that doesn't make them arrays. They neither gain a `.length` nor array methods.

```js
function useLikeAnArray(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  obj[0] = "zero"
  obj[1] = "one"
  obj[2] = "two";
  obj.length = 3;
  console.log(obj);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(obj, el => console.log(el));
}

useLikeAnArray(function greeting() {});
useLikeAnArray({simple: "object"});
useLikeAnArray(null); // oops
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the function, or any other object to an array and iterate with a native method.

```js
function greeting() {
    console.log('hello sir...');
}

greeting();

greeting[0] = "zero";
greeting[1] = "one";
greeting[3] = "two";
greeting[4] = "three";
greeting[5] = "four";
greeting[6] = "five";
greeting[7] = "six";

console.log(greeting[5]);

Object.assign([], greeting).forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign properties to a function but it is still a function.  Here we can see all the properties and the type of those as well as the type of `greeting`

```js
function greeting(){
   // alert('hello sir...')
}

greeting();

greeting[0] = "zero"
greeting[1] = "one"
greeting[3] ="two"
greeting[4] ="three"
greeting[5] ="four"
greeting[6] ="five"
greeting[7] ="six"
console.log("geeting greeting[5] is",typeof greeting[5],greeting[5]);
console.log("greeting is a:",typeof greeting);

for (var key in greeting) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(greeting, key)) {
        var val = greeting[key];
     console.log("key:",key,greeting[key]);
    }
}
```